# Fetch data from database and create listbox in yii

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii

i have a table 'tbl_department' with 2 fields 'dpt_id' n 'dpt_name'
i want to fetch all 'dpt_name' as listbox output on a page.

Comment: Even though this is closed as not a real question, interestingly this was the only reference I found on how to tackle this issue! +1 for the simplicity of the question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

following [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/#hh4) sample from excellent Yii documentation, i've worked out the username from tbl_user. You can get that table, using the minimal sql script **protected/data/schema.mysql.sql** that get installed when you create the empty application with yiic.

```
<?php
    $records = User::model()->findAll();
    $list = CHtml::listData($records, 'id', 'username');
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('names', null, $list, array('empty' => '(Select a name)'));
?>
```

Comment: Really deserve a up-vote guys. Thanks @CapelliC