# loading data from another table in Yii

Tags: model, controller, yii

I am totally new in Yii framework and quite frankly do not know everything about it. I have an ongoing project in which I am stuck in a problem. 
I have 3 tables in the project. Here are the table names and the rows:

1. Users  (id, name, email, username, password, currentTIme)  Uses for storing user information.
2. Groups (id, name, currentTIme) Uses for storing Group Information.
3. UserGroup  (id, userId, groupId, currentTime)  Uses for keeping the relation between user and group.

Now, what I have to do is after creating 3 models, Users and Groups model will be used for all users. Different groups was added like:

1. CSE      02. EEE      03. BBA     04. Architecture etc. etc.

Now, when 'User create' portion 2 things have to happen. One, the group names (CSE, EEE, BBA, Architecture etc.) will be shown in a listbox to choose along with the user's other information (name, password etc.). Now question is How I can show the name of Groups in a listbox in the model Users where there is no relationship.

Second problem is, when I will click 'submit' it will update 2 tables  'Users' and 'UserGroup'. Name, password,currentTime will be saved in 'User' and userid(of current user), groupid(id of the groups user will be selected like 1 for CSE etc.) will be saved in 'UserGroup' table.

Thank you for tolerating my horrible English and any kind of comment/feedback will be a big help for me.....Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a great documentation, why don't you read it?

Comment: These may well help:

a) [Fetch data from database and create listbox in yii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999868/fetch-data-from-database-and-create-listbox-in-yii),

b) [One form and mulitple models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122843/one-form-and-mulitple-models)

Comment: @Orcs, can you please give me some link of documents. I am new in Yii.

Comment: @Stu, Thanks a lot, I am reading this and its very useful. Thanks a LOT......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out answer of the first part which shows the list from another model. For anybody like me, it can be useful i am posting it here.

in the /models/users.php:

class Users extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $Groups;
.......................
.......................
}

in the /view/users/_form.php:

```
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Group'); ?>
<?php
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'Groups',
CHtml::listData(Groups::model()->findAll(),'id','name'));

//echo $form->;dropDownList($model,'Groups', CHtml::listData(Groups::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'value'), array('empty'=>;'--please select--')); 
?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
</div>
```